# Need to check if a variable is equal to any array variable to conditionally add a classname in JSX

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to add an active class to a div in a navigation system in React if the window is on a current url path. I am able to easily do this if I only have one path to compare with the current window path. I am stuck on how to check if the current path is equal to more than one possile paths.

I check the path and assign the navigational item paths for each nav section like so:

```
const signOn = "/upload";
const currentPath = window.location.pathname;
```

And then I check to see if the user is on the current path like so:

```
<li id="nav-item-in" className={ classNames({"active": currentPath === signOn}, "sidebar-item")}>
  <div className="active-carat"></div>    
</li>
```

I have attempted to check for multiple paths by doing this: 
    const sidebarInfo = this.props.sidebarInfo;
    const currentPath = window.location.pathname;

```
const audiencesPath = "/audiences"
const usersPath = "/users"
const clientsPath = "/clients"
const partersPath = "/partner_link"
const adminPaths = [audiencesPath, usersPath, clientsPath, partersPath];

<li id="nav-item-in" className={ classNames({"active": currentPath === adminPaths}, "sidebar-item")}>
  <div className="active-carat"></div>    
</li>
```

The above doesn't work, I am unclear on how to do this within setting the active class on my li item.

Answer (score 0):

`.indexOf()` would be a great help here. How about something like this?

```
const audiencesPath = "/audiences"
const usersPath = "/users"
const clientsPath = "/clients"
const partersPath = "/partner_link"
const adminPaths = [audiencesPath, usersPath, clientsPath, partersPath];

<li id="nav-item-in" className={ classNames({"active": adminPaths.indexOf(currentPath) > -1}, "sidebar-item")}>
  <div className="active-carat"></div>    
</li>
```

This assumes that `window.location.pathname` contains one of the paths in `adminPaths`

If the `currentPath` doesn't exist in the adminPath's array, then -1 is returned. When the `currentPath` is found, it will return the index of it in the adminPath's array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to search in the array to see if there is a match and use that to drive the `active` class:

```
const audiencesPath = "/audiences"
const usersPath = "/users"
const clientsPath = "/clients"
const partersPath = "/partner_link"
const adminPaths = [audiencesPath, usersPath, clientsPath, partersPath];

<li id="nav-item-in" className={ classNames({"active": adminPaths.find((path)=>path===currentPath)}, "sidebar-item")}>
  <div className="active-carat"></div>    
</li>
```

Something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com) and check array inclusion with it

```
import R from 'ramda'

const audiencesPath = "/audiences"
const usersPath = "/users"
const clientsPath = "/clients"
const partersPath = "/partner_link"
const adminPaths = [audiencesPath, usersPath, clientsPath, partersPath];

<li id="nav-item-in" className={ classNames({"active": R.contains(currentPath, adminPaths)}, "sidebar-item")}>
  <div className="active-carat"></div>    
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you want is to check if something exist in an array. So, you can use [array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
<li id="nav-item-in" className={ classNames({"active": adminPaths.includes(currentPath)}, "sidebar-item")}>
  <div className="active-carat"></div>    
</li>
```